# Which is more performant for binary data: write an entire object into a file or separated variables (no object)?

Tags: c++, serialization, binary

What is the most performant way to write and read data in binary mode:

Write and read an entire object (without pointers, only a few attributes) into a FILE or just write each variable separated e.g. `int`, `float`, etc?

Always using `fstream` read() and write() functions.

Comment: memory mapped file would be probably fastest way

Comment: Likely I/O bound regardless. C++ is pretty fast, your disk won't keep up either way.

Comment: General rule of thumb is that writing few larger chunks will almost always be better than writing many small chunks, for at least two major reasons - reduced number of individual function calls (and system calls) and not having to interpret and deal with every different data type in a different way (i.e. the more you can imagine your data as simply a byte stream, the better). However, you still have to think about things like byte order (portability) and dealing with non-POD data, so there's not one single universal answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a simple struct made of primitive data members (int, float, etc...), then writing it to a file this way is faster than traversing the members one by one:

```
the_fstream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&obj),sizeof(obj))
```

Comment: Avoid C-style casts please :(  — _especially_ when it's a `reinterpret_cast`.